# Using an intentService or are there better ways?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I'm creating an app that will do the following:

If a mail comes in with a messageword. It needs to start to locate the phone by GPS functionality. after that it must show the result to the user.

I already have it working with using a broadcastreceiver for fetch the message. After that is starts an Activity. If don the userinterface is updated.

I have here two problems:

1) if the screen rotates all variables are set to zero... well can solve that with saving variables at `onPause()` and read those values at `onResume()`

2) if the user use the backbutton... the thread is cancelled.

Actually I want that the user can't cancel the GPS-action.

Is it a good idea to use an Intentservice for this?!

-message comes in

-`BroadcastReceiver` fetch the message and start the intentService

-if the processing is done... I can start an activity with the results (and the service is closed automaticly after the processing is done?!

Is there maybe a better way to attack the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can and should use an `IntentService` for long running operations in the background. However, if the user backed out of your activity, they most probably did this for a reason, and popping up an activity with results they might not care about anymore, might not be such a good strategy. You could cache the result instead, and show it next time the user opens your activity.